# Display Discount % when selecting some payment methods on checkout page (Onepage)

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, shopping-cart-price-rules

This is a very challenging thing for me. I gave up and I'm asking for help :)

1. How Do I Display the Discount % for some payment methods on the checkout (onepage)?

Customer sees:

Select your Payment Method:

- Bank Transfer 3% Discount on your purchase
- Credit Card
- Check 3% Discount on your purchase
- Purchase Order 3% Discount on your purchase

**I have so far:**

```
$...get Model
<?php if ($rule->getIsActive()) {
        echo $discount .'%'.' Discount on your purchase';
     } ?>
```

**I need:**

```
<?php if ($rule->getIsActive()) {
       if ($rule applies to bank_transfer, check memmo, purchase order ) {
        echo $discount .'%'.' Discount on your purchase';
     } ?>
```

2. How Do I apply this code to all payments at the same time without adding it to each payment.phtml file?

The Shopping Cart Rule has been set already. (RULE ID: 1)

I can just show a text with the message on each payment where the rule applies, but The rule changes sometimes and I don't want to change the text manually every single time. And i dont want to place the code on each payment.phtml file.
Thanks

Comment: thanks for your help. I was able to do this after a few days.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to display a normal message if one payment method is selected in Magento 1.9
can you help me on that?